# $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n a_n = \pi$, $a_n\in \mathbb Q$ and not $a_n$ not monotonic

Tags: sequences-and-series, pi

How can I construct a sequence $\{a_n\}$ of positive rational numbers, which is not monotonic such that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n a_n = \pi$$
I thought a lot on this question but I always come up with a monotonic sequence. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Take your favorite sequence $(a_i)$ of rationals such that your sum converges to $\pi$. Form a new series as follows: after the $a_i$ become less than $1/10$, insert terms $1/10$ and $- 1/10$ as appropriate.  After the $a_i$ become less than $1/100$, insert terms $1/100$ and $-1/100$ as appropriate ...

Comment: pick your favorite monotonic sequence such that $\sum (-1)^n a_n = \pi$, and then swith $a_0$ with $a_2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Madhava formula, we have
$$\pi = 4 - \dfrac43 + \dfrac45 - \dfrac47 \pm = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n 4}{(2n+1)}$$
We can write $\dfrac1{2n+1} = \dfrac{k\sqrt{n}+1}{2n+1} - \dfrac{k\sqrt{n}}{2n+1}$. Hence, we have
$$\pi = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( (-1)^n\dfrac{\sqrt{n}+4}{2n+1} + (-1)^{n+1}\dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{2n+1}\right) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n a_n$$
Writing it out, we see 
$$\pi = \dfrac{\sqrt{0} + 4}{2 \cdot 0 + 1} - \dfrac{\sqrt{0}}{2 \cdot 0 + 1} + \dfrac{\sqrt{1}}{2 \cdot 1 + 1} - \dfrac{\sqrt{1} + 4}{2 \cdot 1 + 1} + \dfrac{\sqrt{2} + 4}{2 \cdot 2 + 1} - \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2 \cdot 2 + 1} + \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2 \cdot 3 + 1} - \dfrac{\sqrt{3} + 4}{2 \cdot 3 + 1} + \cdots$$
where $a_n$'s are as desired, i.e.,
$$a_n = \begin{cases} \dfrac{\sqrt{2k}+4}{2 \cdot (2k)+1} & \text{ if $n = 4k$}\\ \dfrac{\sqrt{2k}}{2 \cdot (2k)+1} &\text{ if $n=4k+1$}\\ \dfrac{\sqrt{2k+1}}{2 \cdot(2k+1)+1} & \text{ if $n=4k+2$}\\ \dfrac{\sqrt{2k+1}+4}{2 \cdot(2k+1)+1} & \text{ if $n=4k+3$}\end{cases}$$
Below is the pictorial representation of the sequence $a_n$. The first $44$ values of this sequence are plotted. As you can see from the figure below, the sequence oscillates up and down and is not monotonic.
[image]
Below is the convergence of the partial sum $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^N a_n$ to $\pi$. The $\color{red}{\text{red line}}$ is the value of $\pi$ for reference. You can see how the partial sums converge to $\pi$.
[image]

---

I didn't see $a_n \in \mathbb{Q}$. Here is the answer if you want $a_n \in \mathbb{Q}$. $$\dfrac1{2n+1} = \dfrac2{2n+1} - \dfrac1{2n+1}$$
Hence,
$$\pi = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left({(-1)}^n\dfrac{8}{2n+1} + (-1)^{n+1} \dfrac4{2n+1}\right)$$
$$\pi = \dfrac81 - \dfrac41 + \dfrac43 - \dfrac83 + \dfrac85 - \dfrac45 \pm \cdots$$
Now choose $a_n$'s as follows.
$$a_n = \begin{cases}\dfrac{8}{4k+1} & \text{ if $n=4k$}\\ \dfrac4{4k+1} & \text{ if $n=4k+1$}\\ \dfrac4{4k+3} & \text{ if $n=4k+2$}\\ \dfrac8{4k+3} & \text{ if $n=4k+3$}\end{cases}$$

Comment: I see how you solved it and loved the way you justified it. Thanks a ton. I really appreciate it..

Answer (score 2):

There are a few methods possible for achieving this. One is to make use of Newton's method as it applies to $\sin(x)$ (which will repeatedly overestimate the step by a small amount). That is,

$$
\Delta x = -\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} = -\tan(x)
$$
Choose a starting value slightly above $\pi$, say $a_0=3.5$. Then let $a_n=-\tan(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i)$. Each term will then be of opposing sign relative to the one before it, and it will converge rapidly to $\pi$.

---

EDIT:

Oh, just noticed the "$a_n\in\mathbb{Q}$" condition. This can be enforced by simply using a rational approximation to $\tan$ for each step, simply requiring that it be, for instance, $\frac1m$ for the integer $m$ that makes it nearest to the value of $\tan$ that is a longer step than $\tan$ itself. For instance, the first iteration has $a_1=-\tan(3.5)\approx -0.374$. The nearest value of $m$ is thus $3$, but that makes it a smaller step, so choose $2$, and you have $a_1=-\frac12$.

Then, $-\tan(3)\approx 0.142$, which is nearest to $\frac17$, but that's too short a step, so we take $\frac16$. Now $-\tan(3+1/6)\approx -0.0251$, so the nearest is $\frac1{40}$, but again, too big a step, so use $m=39$. And so on. The sequence of values of $m$ is thus (in absolute value, for each step):
$$
2, 6, 39, 1763...
$$

Comment: Thanks for taking time to look at my question. I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

As a conditionally convergent series can be rearranged to give any value at will, use your favorite of those series (mine happens to be $\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$). The trick is to pick positive terms until the sum is larger than your target $\pi$ (there is $a_0$), then pick enough negative terms to fall bellow (your $a_1$), and keep going.

No, not exactly a nice set of terms, and it can be considered cheating as you need to know your target beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

if $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n a_n $ is **absolutely convergent** then all rearrangement will still converge to the same value.

So take any sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n a_n = \pi$ that is absolutely convergent and rearrange them in a way that are not monotonic.

Comment: I needed that statement to understand the question. Thanks